# Formatting in python with locale

Tags: python, dictionary, locale

I am trying to format a set of a set of numbers to show as as 
xxx,xxx,xxx instead of xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

The formatter iterates over a dictionary, where the values are a list.

This is what it looks like:

```
{'ST': [Decimal('21529992.247811'), 
Decimal('75922363.959394'), Decimal('1.688401841437798245794341100')], 
'LQT': [Decimal('23034058.811000'), Decimal('45706418.420000'), 
Decimal('0.243186493430996726476558100')], 'SR': 
[Decimal('8389288.802664'), Decimal('0393135.373964'), 
Decimal('-2.146515189191049793306943120')], 'MIS7': 
[Decimal('6382868.080000'), Decimal('5336228.320000'), 
Decimal('-4.879627090905261579809913330')], 'LQ': 
[Decimal('98508613.709000'), Decimal('38822011.125000'), 
Decimal('-3.983067033313078110002846960')] }
```

This is the incorrect coding that I have:

```
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
    for k in result.keys():
        if result[k] == result[k]:
            result[k] = locale.format('%d', result[k], grouping = True)
    if len(result) == 0:
        result["None"] = "None"
```

My error string is long, but this looks like the main bit:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list
```

What do I need to do? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
    for r in result:
        for k in result[r]:
            print locale.format('%2f', k, grouping = True) # Note there is not result[k]. Use your preferred number format instead of '%2f'
```

and here is the output using `'%2f'`:

```
23.034.058,811000
45.706.418,420000
0,243186
8.389.288,802664
393.135,373964
-2,146515
6.382.868,080000
5.336.228,320000
-4,879627
98.508.613,709000
38.822.011,125000
-3,983067
21.529.992,247811
75.922.363,959394
1,688402
```

Comment: Tried it!  Here is my error: "TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str"

Comment: Working fine here. Please note the changes in my code. PS: `result` is your `dict`, of course

Comment: Sort of - I presented a simplified version of my code here. The entire thing also goes through a website.

Comment: pressed enter too quick. Anyway, rather than iterating over the list and formatting the data on the website, a blank page is loaded with one formatted number with your code.

Comment: @ifthenifthen, got it. Did the code above answer to your question? There is not the error you mentioned in the first comment. Please, pay attention to the code.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your new solution. If it wasn't clear I'm SuPeR n00b.

Comment: Don't worry. That code basically iterates over your lists and over your `Decimal` items in lists, then it uses [`local.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.format) to format each value `k`. Is should solve what you asked in your question. :)

Comment: What do you mean by %2f? I am too much a noob to have a preferred number format.

Comment: I through your code in and I got this error:     for r in result:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: Ok, don't worry about %2f, you can also use %d like in your example. Basically, it Is just a way to tell Python how to format displayed numbers (e.g., decimal digits, etc...). For example, take a look here https://pyformat.info

Comment: It is not possible. In the code above, you are just iterating over values to print them. And if you try it as it is, it works. Other issues could come from different statements in your local code. Hope this can help!

Comment: Some of my values will have NaNs and Nones. Could that explain the dictionary "changing size" ?

Comment: I modified it slightly to account for NaNs, and now I am getting KeyError: Decimal('xxxx.xxxx')